# "Geodesic coherent" partition of a graph

Tags: graph-theory, mg.metric-geometry, partitions, metric-spaces, bipartite-graphs

Let $G=(V,E)$ be a finite undirected graph which we equip with its usual graph *geodesic distance* $d_G$ making $(G,d_G)$ into a metric space; let $1<\#V<\infty$.  For a given $1<N< \#V$ *what conditions do I need* on $G$ so that does there exist *disjoint* subsets $V_1,\dots,V_N\subseteq V$ such that

- $\biguplus_{n=1}^N\, V_n = V$,
- $d_{(V_n,E_n)}(x,y)=d_{G}(x,y)$ for every $x,y\in V_n$,

Here $E_n:=\{(v,w):\,v,w\in V_n\}$ *denotes the collection of edges connecting any two vertices in the "part" $V_n$* and where $d_{(V_n,E_n)}$ denotes the graph geodesic defined on the graph $(V_n,E_n)$ *(note, for arbitrary choices of $\{V_n\}_{n=1}^N$ we always have $d_{(V_n,E_n)}\ge d_G$)*.

Comment: Maybe you want to formulate the question in a more precise way? For some $G$ and $N$ it is possible, and for some not.

Comment: @AntonPetrunin I added some clarification and details; but generally, I'm looking for conditions on G for when this can happen.

Comment: An easy condition would be too much to expect. Even for $N=2$.

Comment: @AntonPetrunin Oh by "easy condition" I mean perhaps a simple class of graphs G admitting such a decomposition

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Pilipczuk and Siebertz](https://arxiv.org/abs/1807.03683) proved that every planar graph has such a partition with an even stronger property.  Namely, each part $V_i$ is a geodesic path, and the graph obtained by contracting each part has [treewidth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treewidth) at most 8.  This result was strengthened by [Dujmović, Joret, Micek, Morin, Ueckerdt, and Wood](https://arxiv.org/abs/1904.04791)
, who proved that every planar graph is a subgraph of the [strong product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_product_of_graphs) of a graph of treewidth at most 8 and a path.  This theorem is now known as the Planar Graph Product Structure Theorem and has been the key tool in settling several long standing open problems on planar graphs.  Similar partitions exist for other graph classes (beyond planar).  Determining which graph classes admit a product structure theorem is now a very active research area.  As a start, see this
[survey](https://arxiv.org/abs/2001.08860) and the references therein for more information.

**Disclaimer.** I am one of the authors of the above survey.

Comment: Wow amazing answer!  Thanks so much; this seems to be exactly what I was looking for (+ more since it has nice background + history) thanks a million :)

Comment: Also are there quantitative estimates on the number N?

Comment: That's a good question.  The proof is constructive, but I think the bounds on N can be quite bad.  See https://arxiv.org/abs/2202.08870 for an algorithm that computes the decomposition.

Comment: For your now (deleted) question, such a partition is sometimes called a *layered partition*, since the parts can actually be chosen to be 'vertical paths' from a fixed BFS spanning tree.  Thus, each part intersects each 'layer' of the tree at most once.